# Fatal error: Call to undefined function doGet() in Cron.php

Tags: php, xml, api, soap, cron

I am trying to make an XML request to an external webservices API using but I keep getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function doGet()
```

The problem is with this line:

```
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(doGet (getBaseUrl ("GetAllChassis_WithYears") . "&manufacturerID=$manufacturerId"));
```

But I don't understand why it isn't defined???

Here's my script

```
<?php

    class Namespace_Module_Model_Cron
    {

        public function setHeaders ()
        {

            header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 2020 05:00:00 GMT");
            header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate ("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
            header ("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
            header ("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
            header ("Pragma: no-cache");
            session_start ();
            $vehicle = $_SESSION["vehicle"];
            if (!isset($vehicle)) {
                $vehicle = array();
                $_SESSION["vehicle"] = $vehicle;
            }

        }

        public function appendSessionId ()
        {

            return ini_get ("use_trans_sid" !== true) ? htmlspecialchars (SID) : "";

        }

        public function doGet ($url)
        {
            $ch = curl_init ($url);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
            $response = curl_exec ($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);
            return $response;
        }

        public function checkXmlErrors ($xml)
        {
            if ($xml === false) {
                echo "<p>Failed loading XML</p>";
                foreach (libxml_get_errors () as $error) {
                    echo "<p>" . $error->message . "</p>";
                }

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public function getBaseUrl ($method)
        {
            $username = "username";
            $password = "password";
            $baseUrl = "http://api.wheelwizards.net/eu/webservice.asmx/";
            return $baseUrl . $method . "?username=$username&password=$password";
        }

        public function getAllChassis ($manufacturerId)
        {
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(doGet (getBaseUrl ("GetAllChassis_WithYears") . "&manufacturerID=$manufacturerId"));
            if (checkXmlErrors ($xml)) {
                $chassis = array();
                foreach ($xml->AllChassisReturn as $AllChassisReturn) {
                    $chass = array();
                    $chass["id"] = (string)$AllChassisReturn->ChassisID;
                    $chass["title"] = (string)$AllChassisReturn->ChassisTitle . " " . (string)$AllChassisReturn->UKYear;
                    $chassis[] = $chass;
                }

                // Sort by title
                $titles = array();
                foreach ($chassis as $key => $value) {
                    $titles[$key] = $value["title"];
                }
                array_multisort ($titles, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $chassis);
                Mage::log ($xml, Zend_Log::INFO, 'layout.log', true);
                return $chassis;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public function getAllManufacturers ()
        {
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(doGet (getBaseUrl ("GetAllManufacturers_WithYears")));
            if (checkXmlErrors ($xml)) {
                $manufacturers = array();
                foreach ($xml->AllManufacturersReturn as $AllManufacturersReturn) {
                    $manufacturer = array();
                    $manufacturer["id"] = (string)$AllManufacturersReturn->ManufacturerID;
                    $manufacturer["name"] = (string)$AllManufacturersReturn->ManufacturerName;

                    $manufacturers[] = $manufacturer;
                }

                // Sort by name
                $names = array();
                foreach ($manufacturers as $key => $value) {
                    $names[$key] = $value["name"];
                }
                array_multisort ($names, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $manufacturers);
                Mage::log ($xml, Zend_Log::INFO, 'layout.log', true);
                return $manufacturers;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public function getAllModels ($chassisId)
        {
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(doGet (getBaseUrl ("GetAllModels_WithYears") . "&chassisID=$chassisId"));
            if (checkXmlErrors ($xml)) {
                $models = array();
                foreach ($xml->AllModelsReturn as $AllModelsReturn) {
                    $model = array();
                    $model["id"] = (string)$AllModelsReturn->ModelID;
                    $model["name"] = (string)$AllModelsReturn->ModelName;
                    $models[] = $model;
                }

                // Sort by name
                $names = array();
                foreach ($models as $key => $value) {
                    $names[$key] = $value["name"];
                }
                array_multisort ($names, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $models);
                Mage::log ($xml, Zend_Log::INFO, 'layout.log', true);
                return $models;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `doGet()` belongs to a class and you are calling as normal function. it should be called with `$this->doGet()`

Comment: Because the method isn't defined. It's a part of a class. This isn't your code, right?

Comment: @N.B No, it some code I have to edit in order to make the correct call to the webservice but there's no documentation and I'm struggling at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`doGet()` should be  `$this->doGet()`

Comment: Thankyou, I've changed `doGet()` to `$this->doGet()` now I get exception `Invalid callback: vehicleimport/cron::GetAllChassis does not exist`.